# Что ни день() то() праздник

Tags: фразеология, пунктуация

Как правильно пишется:

Что ни день() то() праздник.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перед **то** надо ставить запятую (отделяет придаточную часть предложения от главной), после **то** - нет. Вместо запятой можно поставить интонационное тире.

Answer (score 2):

Что ни день, то праздник. Это СПП с придаточным уступительным, союзное слово ЧТО НИ  определяет полноту проявления того, о чём говорится в главном предложении. Думаю, что структура предложения не позволяет использовать тире, пауза здесь явно отсутствует.

Для примера я приведу несколько предложений, в которых ставится авторское тире, обозначающее увеличенную паузу:

Едва только раздались первые выстрелы, – ожила безлюдная степь (пропущено "КАК"). 
Коли ты честный – не водись с бесчестными (пропущено "ТО").
Сколько бы ни смотреть на море – оно никогда не надоест.

Comment: Я могу произнести и с паузой: логическое ударение на слово ЧТО, повышение голоса к концу придаточного и пауза...

Comment: Выражение имеет устойчивый характер, произносится как единое целое.